# Having and issues with UIScrollView and Storyboards in Xcode

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, storyboard

So I have a UIScroll view with constraints which position it to the outer borders of the root view - Check

Inside of the UIScrollview I have a VIEW which serves as container for the scrollview.

The issues I'm having is that this view is that even though the bottom constraint is set to equal to the bottom of the scrollview it collapses to a height of 0 in the interface. This hides all of the views inside of the container view making is almost impossible to build the interface...very annoying..what am I missing here?

here is my constraint chart...this is really got me pulling out my hair.

See how the "view" height is 0 and also the Important Message goes to 0 height as well.

[image]

Comment: can you show your full constraint snapshot?

Comment: I'm sorry like a screen capture...?

Answer (score 0):

I attach a screenshot of my project's document outline which shows whole list of autolayout configurations.I think it will help you to figure out your problem.

[image]

enter image description here
[image: This is a list of ScrollView's constraints]

[image: This is a list of ContainerView's constraints]